# android mapview not working

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, android-mapview, self-signed

This is killing me!!!

I seem to have done all I need to do but it just wont work!

here is what i did:

-created a keystore using keytool:

`$ keytool -genkey -v -keystore PADReleaseKey.keystore -alias pocket_aces_release -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000`

-got the MD5 fingerpring from it and used:

`$ keytool -list -alias pocket_aces_release PADReleaseKey.keystore`

-used it to get the mapAPI key and embedded it inside my application:

```
<com.google.android.maps.MapView
    android:layout_weight="1" android:id="@+id/mapview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:apiKey="0qLwM2TNe70Ho-Y1wZiN2MqF_jFIXLc-0gwLRsw"        
    android:clickable="true"/>
```

- exported a signed application package using eclipse and the keystore and alias I have created before.
- installed it on my android machine using adb install.

but still no map is showing!!!! I have done this several times, but it does not work...

can anyone point me to what am i doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: By "android machine" you mean real device or the emulator?

Comment: I also created a simple map application and signed it with the key and it worked. but my other application signed by the same key dows not work... its insane!!!

Comment: Did you ever figure out what was wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say "no map is showing" could you elaborate on that a little more? Are you seeing a load of grey blank squares? If so thats normally an issue with your API key.

Also are you running it on an emulator that has the Google APIs target? I wrote a really [basic guide](http://www.jameselsey.co.uk/blogs/techblog/android-how-to-display-a-map-the-easy-way/) on getting maps working, it may help you.

Regards

Comment: I am getting gray blank squares and I am not using an emulator its my own device.

Comment: Did you update the AndroidManifest file to include the uses library AND the INTERNET permissions? They need to be in the correct place also.

Comment: as I said I have done it several times and still no good. is it possible it takes time for google to update its database with new registered keys?

Comment: I have added <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
 before my application node and <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
 inside the application node and above the activities

Comment: can you think on anyting else? please... its getting quit frustrating here

Comment: Silly question, but can you actually access the internet on your phone? Can you open up the browser and access Google.com?

Comment: Also go thru the link I posted and copy/paste the exact source code at the bottom, you might have missed something small

Comment: :) yes right before i am using the maps i get something from the internet. the google accout on the phone is different than the one I am using to create the google api key ( dont think it matters because everyone who installes it will be in the same situation)

Comment: if you need any more information from me just ask. i will try the blog post

Comment: @James.Elsey your tutorial worked! i have signed it and installed the app to my device and it worked! saddly when using the same mapapi key on my app I am not getting any maps. how is this possible?

Comment: No idea mate, at least without seeing your code. Glad I helped tho thats why I'm blogging / trawling SO :)

Comment: @James.Elsey It seems there is something wrong with my application because I used the release key with another simple app I created just to chek and it worked... the only question is what is wrong :)

Comment: No idea without seeing all your sourcecode. Probably something with the XML files maybe, but thats just speculation.

Comment: I have the same issue. You found the solution??