# Using the Google map API in Android, using a proxy

Tags: android, google-maps

I am using the google map API in a very basic app. But the problem is that on running the app, I only see the grid and the map controls...the map doesnt even load in the virtual device.
I have internet running in the device...the browser seemed to be loading just fine, so it isnt an internet problem.
Also, i did obtain an API key after registering for the map API and included that in my main.xml file...but still it doesnt show the map...just grids.The permissions for using the internet are also granted in the manifest file.
Im using the Google API level 8.Any idea how to fix this?
thx.
**EDIT 1**: Can anyone please help me out with this...really need help :(

**EDIT 2**: Well I found the following error in my LogCat:
`Sending checkin request`
`Checkin failed: https://android.clients.google.com/checkin (request #0)`
`org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeOutException: Connect to /209.85.231.100:44 timed out`

So basically my connection is timing out...im not really sure why...could anyone provide some fix for this plz?( but the AVD's browser is able to work perfectly, no time out problems..sites are able to load properly)
Also, the pre-installed maps application is showing the following error:
`**Network Failure** Wrong remote strings version.GMM Server must be hosting:/strings_remote_533149424.dat`
If you know any way i could fix this, it would be extremely helpful...
Thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently if you are using a proxy, and have set that in your APN, then your AVD cannot load any application that is using the map, neither the pre-installed one, nor any created by you.
Reference: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=3764#makechanges
Unfortuantely there is no solution for this (yet).
Thx to all who helped :)
PS: If any1 found a solution using the proxy...or any other way to fix this...do post here..

Answer (score 2):

You should not make your network(proxy) settings in your emulator or device. Just open your network settings in your PC. Then go the properties. you will find the list of items in your connections. go to IPV4 and set your default gateway and DNS server.

I faced the same error

```
**Network Failure** Wrong remote strings version.GMM Server must be hosting:/strings_remote_533149424.dat
```

Then i followed the above steps. I got the output.....Just check out and reply....

Comment: The network settings were in place on the PC, along with the proxy settings in internet options, but even after this the problem persisted. Infact, on the emulator, the browser only works if you have the proxy settings set on the emulator (regardless if the settings are set on your PC as well).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that these permissions are in your manifest file, outside the closing application tag:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_GPS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Comment: yea...internet permissions are also granted...still doesnt work

Comment: Its also worth noting that the uses permission/library has to be in a certain place in the AndroidManifest.xml as detailed in the link in my answer

Answer (score 0):

Is your emulator connected to the internet? some times the emulator fails to connect to the internet when it boots, you should see a 3g sign on your notification bar.

Comment: yes..i can use the browser to access the internet...im using a proxy for the internet here..so i had to put that in..but the internet works fine. Also, the pre-installed maps application in the virtual device is not working too, its also showing just the grid.

Comment: Well, then the problem is somewhere else. If you cannot see it within the Maps application, I doubt you'll get it to work in your own app.

Answer (score 0):

Seen this issue posted many times, and have written up a really [easy tutorial](http://www.jameselsey.co.uk/blogs/techblog/android-how-to-display-a-map-the-easy-way/) which has helped folk such as this [previous question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4924591/android-mapview-not-working/4924617#4924617)

It generally tends to be one of 3 issues :

1. API key is incorrect
2. You are using the standard Android emulator and not the Google APIs.
3. You have extended Activity instead of MapActivity

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have checked and re-checked my API key. It really is correct.
Im using the Google API emulator with API level 8.
I have extended the correct Activity... :( still doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely due to the API-key being wrong. Make sure you're using the correct API-key. (The key will be different for your debug certificate (keystore) and the certificate you use to sign the APK before you publish it to Android Market).

> To generate an MD5 fingerprint of the debug certificate, first locate the debug keystore. By default, build tools create the debug keystore in the active AVD directory. The location of the AVD directories varies by platform:
>
> Windows Vista: C:\Users\.android\debug.keystore
>
> Windows XP: C:\Documents and Settings\.android\debug.keystore
>
> OS X and Linux: ~/.android/debug.keystore

See http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/mapkey.html for more details.

Comment: Im sure my API key is correct, but even if it was wrong, thats no reason for the pre-installed Maps application not to work... :(

Comment: Yeah, I didn't notice your comment on another answer about using a proxy, and that the pre-installed Maps application didn't work either.