# Unable to show Google Maps using WiFi behind a proxy

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, wifi

I have created a simple app which shows a Google Map.  I am testing it on a HTC Desire S and I am using only WiFi network behind a proxy.  But it is not showing anything, only map tile are shown in the screen. Even the default map application is not working. It shows the error message that

"Network Failure : wrong remote string version.GMM server must be hosting:/ string_remote_no-remote-strings."

My Map API key is correct and I have added the following permissions in the manifest file:

```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Have you a new api key for phones? you have to use one for emulator , one for devices . But if api key is not correct i remember that no message appears. Have you looked over http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5109139/using-the-google-map-api-in-android-using-a-proxy ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure

1. you extended `MapActivity`?
2. your API Key is correct?

Apparently if you are using a proxy, and have set that in your APN, then your AVD cannot load any application that is using the map, neither the pre-installed one, nor any created by you.

Check http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=3764#makechanges

Comment: That means there is no solution for showing the google maps with proxy setting even in the real device ?