# Current Location Google Maps Version 2

Tags: android, google-maps

I have been trying for days to simply open up Google Maps and have it animate to my location. I have searched Google and StackOverFlow and tried countless things but I am still not able to accomplish what seems like a simple task. Can someone point me in the right direction for a tutorial that works or offer any guidance?

Comment: try  this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9195433/cant-get-current-location-using-gps/9195798#9195798

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 ways:

1. Get your current location using [Local-Base service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6095919/android-how-to-get-current-location-latitude-and-longitude). Then draw to the map
2. Try this map option:

   mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);